# Separate unsorted list by letter in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and I'd like to take an unsorted list and do the following: http://i.min.us/idAMoq.png

How would one accomplish separating list items based on the beginning letter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used this example HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>Array</li>
<li>Beta</li>
<li>Application</li>
<li>Revolver</li>
<li>Pilot</li>
</ul>
```

Include jQuery library in the `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

jQuery (added after UL or in `$(function(){/*code here*/})`):

```
var output={};
$('ul li').each(function(i,v){
    var l=$(this).text().substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
    if(typeof(output[l])=="undefined") output[l]=[];
    output[l].push($(this).text());
});
$('ul').empty();
for(var i in output){
    $('ul').append('<li><p>'+i+'</p></li>');
    for(var j in output[i]){
        $('ul').append('<li>'+output[i][j]+'</li>');
    }
}
```

and at the end you'll get this HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><p>A</p></li>
<li>Array</li>
<li>Application</li>
<li><p>B</p></li>
<li>Beta</li>
<li><p>R</p></li>
<li>Relolver</li>
<li><p>P</p></li>
<li>Pilot</li>
</ul>
```

---

Hi, small update, pure JS version should be working with prototype, jQuery or without any:)

```
var output={},string="";
var myul=document.getElementById('list');
var myli=myul.getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var x=0;x<myli.length;x++){
    var l=myli[x].innerHTML.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
    if(typeof(output[l])=="undefined") output[l]=[];
    output[l].push(myli[x].innerHTML);
}

for(var i in output){
    string+='<li><p>'+i+'</p></li>';
    for(var j in output[i])string+='<li>'+output[i][j]+'</li>';
}
myul.innerHTML=string;
```

Just stick it below the code or in any onload/ready statement.

---

Cheers

G.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm asking too much but would you have a similar example in Prototype?

Comment: sorry mate, I was a bit busy last few days, I'll have a look, maybe I'll manage to recreate it in prototype or in raw js, cheers